# Can I have a fragment inside another fragment or is better handle as "parallel" fragment into the activity_main.xml layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am absolutly new in Android development and I have the following doubt about fragment.

So I am started from this official example to create a Screen Slides that uses **ViewPager** component: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It works fine and I have adapted the previous example creating a more complex **layout/fragment_screen_slide_page.xml** layout file, this one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />
        <!--
        android:src="@drawable/carbonara"/>
        android:background="@drawable/carbonara" />
        -->


    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="@style/pastaTitleTextStyle" />


</LinearLayout>
```

So it basically contains an header image and a descriptive text under this image. Scrolling right\left the image and the descriptive text change, this is handled by this class:

```
/**
 * A fragment representing a single step in a wizard. The fragment shows a dummy title indicating
 * the page number, along with some dummy text.
 *
 */
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "ScreenSlidePageFragment";
    /**
     * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

    /**
     * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
     */
    private int mPageNumber;

    /**
     * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
     */
    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Method that will be called when the "pasta slider" is slided right or left
     * @param inflater
     * @param container
     * @param savedInstanceState
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       System.out.println("PAGE NUMBER: "+ mPageNumber + 1);

        // Obtain the colosseum_icon.png from the rsources as a Drawable:
        //Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.colosseum_icon);

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
        ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        switch (mPageNumber + 1) {

            case 1:
                imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carbonara);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.carbonara));
                break;

            case 2:
                imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.amatriciana);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.amatriciana));
                break;

            case 3:
                imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gricia_m);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.gricia));
                break;

            case 4:
                imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cacio_e_pepe);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.cacio_e_pepe));
                break;

            case 5:
                imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ajo_ojo_e_peperoncino);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.ajo_ojo_peperoncino));
                break;

            default:
                imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carbonara);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.carbonara));
        }

        //imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carbonara);

        // Set the title view to show the page number.
        //((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
     */
    public int getPageNumber() {
        return mPageNumber;
    }
}
```

I works fine.

So basically it is used to select a cooking recipes: scrolling right\left the user select a specific recipe and the text of the **TextView** having **android:id="@android:id/text1"** is the current recipe name.

Now I have to implement the recipe instruction and here I have some doubt about how correctly implement my idea.

I was thinking to implement something like a "nested" slideshow for the recipe steps.

So the application works in this way:

1) First the user select a specific recipe scrolling right\left the implemented **ViewPager** (as it done into the previous article).

2) Then the user can scroll again into this fragment to se the various cooking steps for the selected recipe (for example: STEP 1: ingredints list, STEP 2: how to cook, STEP 3: how to present on the table).

So now my doubt is: can I insert something like a new fragment into my **layout/fragment_screen_slide_page.xml** layout file, something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/stepsPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

or this is not a good solution and I have to put this element into my **activity_main.xml** main actibity layout under the first **ViewPager** component (the one used to select the recipe) and handle the content by Java code? So doing something like this into the **activity_main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.pastafromrome.MainActivity">

    <!-- This is used to select the recipe: -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- This show the steps of the selected recipe: -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/stepsPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the correct solution to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: You can have nested `Fragment`. You will have to use `Fragment` method  `getChildFragmentManger()` for adding child fragments instead of `getFragmentManger()`. You should avoid nested scrolling in your layout, if nested `ViewPager` will create nested scrolling then you should avoid it.

Comment: @Sharj Why I have to avoid nested scrolling? What is the reason?

Comment: In general a Scroll View within a Scroll view doesn't work good, like if you put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. Android has released a special `NestedScrollView` view recently that can handle multiple scroll views. In your case, if you use nested ViewPager then you have to take care of touch events for both yourself that could be tricky.